# VB - background sound play in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I’m writing application in Visual Basic for Windows Phone 8.1 the app will countdown and at the end of this it plays sound. The problem is that when phone is locked or application is in background instead of playing sound the app generates an error. When app is not to play sound (parts of code which plays sound are comented) the app cuntdown correctly even in background or when the phone is locked

To play sound I use MediaElement and files stored locally. Do you know what to do to make my app works properly ?

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Might be useful:  Background Audio -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx